# Linear mixed model - matrix is rank deficient

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a linear mixed model to my dataset and I keep getting a strange message:

```
"fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient"
```

Right now my model code is:

```
 m0 <- lmer(y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + (1|var4))
```

where y is a numeric response variable and variables 1-4 are factors.

What could this possibly mean?

Comment: check for NA values in your data

Comment: It means that `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` (the fixed effects) are multicollinear, i.e. there is some linear combination of them that's constant.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my initial run so I checked the variables I had included and one of them (a factor variable) only had 1 level.  So I removed it and it worked.  Also make sure you don't have NA's in your variables.

To check for NA's:

```
sapply(data[, c(variable_names), with=FALSE], function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

To drop NA's:

```
data_no_NAs <- na.omit(data[, c(variable_names), with = FALSE])
```